I worked/was working late at the office
Sarah usually returns home from work at 6:00 pm, but this time and the previous time, she came home late. As a result, she and John had the following conversation at 11:00 pm:
Dialog #1:
John: "Sarah, I noticed you got home late again. What happened?"
Sarah: "I worked late at the office to finish up a project. There was just so much to do before the deadline."
Dialog #2:
John: "Sarah, I noticed you got home late again. Also, I called you at 8:00 pm today, but you didn't pick up. What happened?"
Sarah: "I was working late at the office to finish up a project. There was just so much to do before the deadline."
Question:
In dialog #1, there's no specific time mentioned in John's question, so Sarah uses the simple past in her response.
In dialog #2, there's a specific time mentioned, so she uses the past continuous: she was still working at 8:00 pm when John called.
Are the tenses used correctly? If so, would it also be correct to use the past continuous "was working" in the first dialog, and the simple past "worked" in the second? Thanks.

If they're a couple, why didn't she tell him why she was late as soon as she arrived home?

@KateBunting He didn't ask her the first time, so she didn't think that he wanted to know.

You need to understand that the choice of tense doesn't begin with "Which tense is right?" but with "Which tense communicates the right meaning?" In both of your examples, either tense will be right if it results in you saying what you wanted to say.
In dialog #1, worked or was working are both correct, and both mean basically the same thing. There might be a small difference of focus. Was working points more to the time period. (I was working during the whole of that time frame.) Worked points more to the result of the work, and possibly implies that I did indeed get the project finished. But even if this is correct it is a subtle difference.
In dialog #2 the only addition is the reference to the telephone call at 8.00 pm. This is a classic example of my opening comment. It's not about correctness but about intended meaning.
The 8 pm reference by itself makes absolutely no difference grammatically to the choice of tense. Exactly the same elements apply as for dialog #1. Both tenses may be used, and broadly they will mean the same thing. However, depending on the intended meaning, the choice of tense may be critical. This because relationally there are now two possible topics to be answered: (1) Why were you late? and (2) Why didn't you answer my phone call?
If you are answering question (1), the above notes apply as usual. But if you are answering (the implied) question (2), then only one of the tenses will be correct. "I didn't answer your call because I was working late (and didn't hear the phone ringing...)" Here the answer explains what you were doing at the time of the phone call, and the continuous tense is more accurate. Consider the alternative: "I didn't answer your call because I worked late." I don't know if this is technically wrong, but it's definitely unnatural to me, and I can't think of a context where I would say it that way.
